# Google Map problem on IE8

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have a strange problem witch google map on IE. I'm trying to load google map using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
LoadGoogleMap();
}
```

LoadGoogleMap() - is my internal function thats invoke all code needed to load google map.

Everything works great on Firefox, Opera, Chrom, Safari but not on IE :(

I found that I can use this code to load gmap on IE:

```
var timer = setTimeout("initialize()", 1500);
```

But I don't want to wait 1,5s to load gmap. Could anyone help me ?

Comment: You may want to post the code for LoadGoogleMap()

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket for your ready(). Is that really the code that's working in Firefox, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Try binding it on window load perhaps? `$(window).load(function() { loadGMap(); });`

And it would be useful providing an example of it not working in IE.